# Can I use a WindowsFormsHost in a WinUI3 application?

Tags: c#, opengl, winui-3

I have a WinUI3 application where I need to host an OpenGL window from a legacy SDK of which I have no control. OpenGL requires the Windows handle and device context to work. Those are properties available in WindowsForms controls but not in WinUI3. As a work around I'm trying to use a WindowsFormsHost to host a WindowsForms UserControl that works fine on a WPF application. But when I try to use the same solution in the WinUI3 app I get the following error:

**Error XLS0503 A value of type 'WindowsFormsHost' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.**

I added the necessary assembly references and the namespaces resolve correctly. Here is the XAML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="WinUI3OpenGLApp.OpenGLView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3OpenGLApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:int="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms.Integration;assembly=WindowsFormsIntegration"
    xmlns:oglc="clr-namespace:OpenGLManagedLib;assembly=OpenGLManagedDll"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <int:WindowsFormsHost x:Name="windowsFormsHost1">
            <oglc:OpenGLUserControl  x:Name="openGLUserControl1" />
        </int:WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I know that WinUI3 handles graphics in a completely different way than WPF and WindowsForms, so, that must be root of the problem. Is there a way around this to host an OpenGL window in WinUI3?

Comment: WinUI3 has a SwapChainPanel https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel it's probably better to host OpenGL on the DXGI swap chain panel, using this https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/NV/WGL_NV_DX_interop2.txt . There's some code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108346/how-to-use-glimportmemorywin32handleext-to-share-an-id3d11texture2d-keyedmutex-s

Comment: I'll look into that. I saw before the SwapPanel control. My understanding was that it was specific to DirectX, but it's worth to give it a deeper look. 
Meantime, I found that the Win32 hwind handle can be obtained with the xxx.Interop interface in App.Xaml.cs. and in the Window derived class as well. With that I managed to obtain the Win32 device context handle and crate the OpenGL handle. Then call OpenGL to draw and swap on that surface. The code from a Win32 sample compiles and runs without errors, but the graphics don't show up on the window. Maybe it is obscured by the XAML background?.

Comment: It's not SwapPanel, it's SwapChainPanel. Swap chains on Windows are handled by DXGI (and all DirectX 11, 12) above, but obviously yes it's tied to DirectX, that's why I pointed to WGL_NV_DX_interop2 which adds support for DirectX 11. Elements in WinUI3 don't have HWND as this uses Direct Composition (aka the Visual Layer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer). The only good way is to use a SwapChainPanel, but I didn't say it would be an easy trip. You can also hav look at XAML islands https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands

Comment: You can also have a look at this https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4670 (but it doesn't bring any easy solution either)

Comment: Finally, I found a way around following sample code from @castorix [WinUI3_ActiveX_MSRDP](https://github.com/castorix/WinUI3_ActiveX_MSRDP/tree/master). My answer explains how.

Comment: Well maybe it's good enough for you but it doesn't really answer the original questions (ie: "hosting"). You can always create new windows from a Win32 application using Windows API and do whatever you want with it using other Windows API.

Comment: Yes, the short answer to the initial question is that you can't (as far as I know). I missed to mention that you can create a C++/CLI control and derive it from Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::UserControl and host it in a WinUI3 form. Which was the ultimate goal. The solution proposed here may be more useful for those searching on the same subject than just saying "you can't".

Answer (score -1):

After much delving in documentation and googling, I foud the way around the problem. In simple terms I created a CHILD window of the WinUI3 window to overlay it on the desired location. I choosed to fit it inside the a **Border** control.

Step 1 - Grab a handle of the underlying WindowCore of the hosting window.

```
IntPtr HWndOwner = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
```

Step 2 - Create a CHILD Win32 window with the desired size and position on the host window.

```
 IntPtr hchild = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED , "Static", "",
       WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, x, y, width, height, hwndParent, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

 SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hchild, 0, (byte)(255 * nOpacity / 100), LWA_ALPHA);

 ShowWindow(hchild, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Step 3 - Initialize the OpenGL enviroment using the hchild handle (your own code).

Do this in the host window constructor, otherwise (for reasons unknown to me at this time) if you create the child window outside the constructor it won't showup until the host window is moved or resized.

[image]

The final result